# how to prove that the following integral is divergent

Tags: integration

How to prove that $\int_0^{\infty}e^{x^2}dx$ is divergent.
The integrand goes to infinity as x goes to infinity. But I have no idea how to prove it rigorously

Comment: Assume the integral is convergent. Since $e^{x^2}$ is a continuous, positive and increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{x^2}\,dx \geq \int_{M}^{M+1}e^{x^2}\,dx \geq e^{M^2}$$ and since $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is arbitrary, we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $X>0$

we have

$\forall x\in [X,+\infty) e^{x^2}\geq1$

and

$\int_0^Xe^{x^2}dx\geq\int_0^Xdx=X$

when $X$ goes to $+\infty$ the integral
 goes also to $+\infty$ and it's divergent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: compare it with $\int_0^\infty e^x$

Comment: @Elmo  here is easier